# Calculating decimal from most significant bits & least significant bits in PHP

Tags: php, bit

I'm a little stumped here.  I have 2 32-bit integers, one for the most significant bits & the other is the least.  How do I find the decimal equivalent from those two in PHP?

*Update:*
I have tried the suggestion from @bwoebi and modified it a little.  Here's the code:

```
$value=get64($msb, $lsb);

function get64($msb, $lsb) {
    $count = count($lsb);
    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $value[$i] = bcadd(bcmul($msb[$i], bcpow(2, 32)), $lsb[$i] > 0?$lsb[$i]:bcadd(bcsub(bcpow(2, 32), $lsb[$i]), 2 << 30)); // $a most significant bits, $b least significant bits
    }
}
```

Output:

```
msb=Array ( [0] => INTEGER: 0 [1] => INTEGER: 0 ) 
lsb=Array ( [0] => INTEGER: 143 [1] => INTEGER: 0 ) 
value=Array ( [0] => 2147483648 [1] => 2147483648 )
```

The output does not look right...I would have expected 143 as value[0].  Any input?

Comment: So I'm guessing you're running 32-bit PHP; this would probably be easier if you were running 64-bit PHP; though are they signed or unsigned integers?

Comment: @MarkBaker PHP has only signed integers...

Comment: @bwoebi - I know, that's why it makes a difference if OP's integers are unsigned

Comment: @MarkBaker They are unsigned

Comment: @PLui I've updated my answer. Should work now as it should. (I've tested twice every case...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bcadd(bcmul($a, bcpow(2, 32)), $b >= 0?$b:bcsub(bcpow(2, 32), $b)); // $a most significant bits, $b least significant bits
```

should do the job. I am using the bc library as there maybe imprecisions when working with normal operators on the 32 bit systems (It would be converted to float).

Comment: I tried your code with these values: `a=1
b=2147483647
sum=6442450943`  Does that look right?

Comment: @PLui It is right ... 1 * 2^32 + 2^31 - 1 = 3 * 2^31 - 1 = 6442450943 (p.s. It also converts negative $b to an unsigned value: b = -2147483648 (and $a = 0) => 2^32)

Comment: @PLui I think I made some error... -2^32 is `1000...00` and not `111...111`. I've just fixed it.

Comment: One question...the last argument there says `2<<30`.  Why is that?  I'm not sure if I understand.

Comment: @PLui `2 << 30 === 1 << 31 == pow(2, 32)` See for bitshift.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [GNU Multiple Precision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extensions to perform arithmetic with values too large for native PHP variables.